# Hebrew Nikkud on MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, hebrew

I have seen multiple answers related to inserting nikkud (Hebrew vowels) in Microsoft Word. That is *not* my question. My question is as follows:
When I type hebrew with nikkud in MS Word (Font: Frank-Ruehl and others), the nikkud is set below the line, so that the bottom dots of the longer nekudos (kubutz, segol) are partially cut off. I have tried raising the position in the fonts menu, increasing the line spacing, but neither solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Hebrew serif font does not present this problem. The font you mentioned, Frank-Ruehl, does have this problem. Changing the text size or spacing makes no difference.
Essentially, the issue is that MS word is miscalculating how much space the nikkud takes up. I think this is a miscalculation, since Word is willing to give the additional space to other fonts (the standard Hebrew serif font is actually taller than Frank-Ruehl. Word calculates the standard space for the drop, but doesn't provide extra space for the longer nekudos.
My recommendation is to switch to the Hebrew standard serif font (access via Times New Roman). Or you could use DavkaWriter or another Hebrew word processor - Until we come up with a better solution...